# Cannot access Ubuntu web server from other device

Tags: php, ubuntu, webserver, firewall

I run the built-in PHP web server on Ubuntu 12.04:

`php -S 0.0.0.0:8000`

Locally, I can access my website on `http://192.168.xx.yy:8000`. However, I can not access the site from other devices in the same LAN on that same IP-address (the request times out).

I thought the Ubuntu firewall might be blocking the request and did:

`sudo uwf disable`

and

`sudo iptables -F`

but still no luck accessing my site form other devices. Does anyone have a clue on this?